# JPA persist Object with cascase relation and then delete it (hibernate)

Tags: jpa, cascade, bidirectional, persist

I have the following bidirectional 1:n relationship between A user entity and a job entity:

User class:

```
... 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST}) 
    public Collection<Job> getJobs() { 
        return jobs; 
    } 

public void addJob(Job j) { 
    jobs.add(j); 
    j.setUser(this);
} 
...
```

Job class:

```
// Job class 
... 
@ManyToOne 
    public User getUser() { 
        return user; 
    }
```

Now saving a User object (and let hibernate automatically save the job entity) works...
Then when i want to delete the job entity from the db i get an exception ....

```
        User user = new User();
        user.addJob(new Job());


        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        Job j = entityManager.find(Job.class, 1L);

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.remove(j);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: [dst1.model.Job#<null>]
```

why does this happen? btw. when i explicitly call persist with the job object the problem does not occur... but i don't want to persist job seperately, but let hibernate persist them (with cascade, which actually works....)

thx

Comment: i may have an idea, but i'm not sure. could you please add `entityManager.flush()` after the first commit and tell me what happens then. my idea is that it depends on your flushing strategy...

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your reply. Adding entityManager.flush() does not solve the problem. :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the job from the user when you delete the entity:

```
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    j.getUser().getJobs().remove(j);
    entityManager.remove(j);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Or by your own suggestion: Add `orphanRemoval=true` on the jobs collection.

Comment: Thank you. This worked! One alternative way i fugured out is to use orphanRemoval=true on the job collection...